# Request.PhysicalApplicationPath in ASP-MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 6 the Request object doesn't have the Request.PhysicalApplicationPath method, how can I get the executing path then?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **ApplicationBasePath** property on **IApplicationEnvironment** service to get this info.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnv;

    public TestController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        _appEnv = appEnv;
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        return _appEnv.ApplicationBasePath;
    }
}
```